# X server started by kdm dies during startup because of keymap couldn't be loaded

Tags: x11, x-server

I upgraded an OpenSUSE from 11.1 to 13.1, but after the upgrade, the X server refuses to start. If I execute `kdm`, the X server complains in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file that:

```
(EE) Error compiling keymap (server-0)
(EE) XKB: Couldn't compile keymap
XKB: Failed to compile keymap.
Keyboard initialization failed. This could be missing or incorrect setup of xkeyboard-config.
(EE) Fatal server error:
(EE) Failed to activate core devices.(EE)
```

None of the directories are full. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: Do you have `xkb-data` installed? That's the name of the package on Ubuntu - not sure it's the same on SUSE.

Comment: Do you have the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/basic`?

Answer (score 1):

I too faced similar issue in angstrom distribution and found that xkbcomp program is missing. Installing it had fixed the issue.

Try installing the xkbcomp program using the package manager (zypper) of OpenSuse.
Reference for zypper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158838/how-to-install-packages-from-command-line-on-suse